# disable headphone jack in Vista

Tags: windows, audio, headphone-jack

I have a Dell Studio XPS 1645 laptop, it has 1 microphone and 2 headphone jacks.

Problem is, one of the headphone jacks has became faulty and Windows thinks it's constantly in use, thus I can only have sound coming from the headphones and can't force it to come from the speakers.

Is there a way to disable the faulty jack only or force audio to come from speakers in Vista ?

Driver is: `IDT High Definition CODEC`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried blowing it out with compressed air?  I have noticed that on hw some platforms I get gunk in the jack that causes a short placing it always in use.

Answer (score 1):

Can you go to the *Playback* tab on the *Sound* control panel item, select the *Headphones*, click *Properties* and choose *Don't use this device (disable)*?

Comment: tried it, dosn't work, I think sound is still redirected to headphone jacks even tough "Independent (R.T.C) Headphones" device is disabled.